# Неправильно создана матрица через циклы

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, матрицы

Есть матрица которую я создаю через циклы 12x10
Нужно чтобы был столбец не 12-23 а был 12-1.

```
// заполнение массива

int array[12][10], b = 12;

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        array[i][j] = b++;
    }
}

// вывод на экран в консоли

cout << endl;
printf("\t");

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    printf("x(%i)\t", j + 1);
}

cout << endl << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    printf("y(%i)\t", i + 1);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)

    {
        printf("%i\t", array[i][j]);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите? `array[i][j] = b--;`? Задайте вопрос более точно.

Comment: да, но нужно ещё чтобы каждый элемент был больше на 12

Comment: по строке больше на 12, а по столбцу уменьшается на 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас верно понял, вам нужно это?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        array[i][j] = 12*(j+1)-i;
    }
}
```

Если нет - уточняйте вопрос дальше :)

Comment: именно так, спасибо